# XAML trigger not triggering

Tags: c#, xaml, triggers

do you see anything wrong with this trigger?

```
<Border Margin="2" BorderBrush="#6593CF" BorderThickness="1.5" >
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCreating, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Lime"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>

                    </Border>
```

It is bound to this property:

```
private bool _IsCreating = false;
public bool IsCreating
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsCreating;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_IsCreating == value)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _IsCreating = value;            
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsCreating");
            }
        }
```

When I set IsCreating = true, the style does not update.

Comment: Where did you specify the "DataContext" in the XAML ?

Comment: Can you provide the code for "RaisePropertyChanged" ?

Comment: And try Binding="{Binding Path=IsCreating,....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set BorderBrush and BorderThinkness inline on your border. Inline declaration has [quite hight precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) and override your trigger. Remove your inline declaration from border and move it to trigger:

```
<Border Margin="2">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsCreating, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Lime" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsCreating, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#6593CF" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.5" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsCreating}" />
</Border>
```

Comment: Thx 3615 you're 100% right.
I thought the inline values would act as default : wrong assumption :)